# bootstrap4 not responsive on mobile (not a viewport issue)

Tags: html, css, mobile, bootstrap-4

My webpage is responsive and works as expected when I shrink the browser page on my computer, but when loaded on a mobile device it appears only in a zoomed out desktop view - I would like to it appear how it does in the browser.

I have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` in the header.  I'm not using domain cloaking.

Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/NHiNWGrr

[Screenshot on my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTnY8.png)

[Screenshot on phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCS4S.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this i didn't find your issue and i changed width of container to 100vw and gave it a height of 100% which works well
https://kgoyal000.github.io/stackq/

This is on iphone simulator

[image]

It looks fine to me

Comment: Thanks for the response!    I tried giving `max-width:100vw; height: 100%;` to both the containers and nothing seemed to change on mobile.  I also tried using an iphone simulator and got the same result. [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/8cY2Abb.jpg)

Comment: which model you are using iphone model?

Comment: I tried iphone 6, 8, 11 pro, and ipad air 2 on the simulator [link](https://appetize.io/demo?device=iphone6s&scale=75&orientation=portrait&osVersion=13.3)  (My real phone is an LG stylo q plus)